# Why does the following Objective-C code stop when calling method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

I use the following Objective-C code in my iPhone App:

```
NSLog(@"Before JS string definition");
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('ok');"];
NSLog(@"Before JS call");
@try {
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
@catch (id theException) {
    NSLog(@"%@", theException);
}
NSLog(@"JS call string was: %@", jsString);
```

When I run it, I get in the logs:

```
2012-12-13 16:10:34.743 MyApp.com[2328:907] Before JS string definition
2012-12-13 16:10:34.744 MyApp.com[2328:907] Before JS call
```

So, the last NSLog call doesn't get executed. Obviously the call to *stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString* somehow hangs there. No error message in the logs. No exception. Nothing.

What's going on? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that alert() is a synchronous call and will not return until after the user has dismissed the message box.  The method to evaluate JavaScript will not return until after the JavaScript has finished.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply. I see no alert box popup in my app which I could dismiss.

Comment: Weird. I replace alert() with console.log() and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how can you benefit from this code (don't see the purpose, you could generate your own alerts, only if you have some complex javascript logic over just a simple and straight alert();). But note that `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` has a limitation of 10secs for execution and 10mb of ram. Maybe something here is the issue, but as far as I could remember it gives an error to the log of some kind if these restrictions met.

Comment: I just wanted to test if the JavaScript call works. That's why I used alert. Obviously console.log would have been a wiser choice ;-)